# MySQL Server 8.0.14 failed to Install on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

[image: Image for Visual]

I have already installed Visual Studio 2015 x64 Redistributable but still the server failed to install. What could be the reason?

Comment: For the server it is not relevant which C++ runtime you have installed. Check the output of the installer to see what went wrong (click `Show Details`).

Answer (score 16):

I've found this workaround at [MySQL Forums](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?169,668049,677362#msg-677362) that worked for me:

1. Run the installer
2. When the wizard pops, exclude "Server Data Files" (Red "X" on the drive)
3. The wizard will install the server
4. Click the "Reconfigure" link
5. Finish server configuration.

Comment: You are a total lifesaver. Been at this 2 hours and your solution is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,I also failed to install mysql server 8.0.14 and workbench. I checked my distributable.
I repeatedly install VS 2015 64 but I can't install.
Because new VS 20** has been installed.So I uninstalled new VS 20** .And installed VS 2015 64. Finally I can install MySQL Server 8.0.14 after it.
So, please , follow these steps and 
try again to install MySQL Server 8.0.14.
Thank for reading.
My English is bad.

Important

> > > > > You must uninstall the new versions over microsoft visual C++ 2015 redistributable 64. <<<<<

Comment: You do not nedd to uninstall new VS 20** ，just uninstall the new versions over microsoft visual C++ 2015 redistributable. (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) Download the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019. The following updates are the latest supported Visual C++ redistributable packages for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019. Included is a baseline version of the Universal C Runtime see MSDN for details.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, using the web installation.
"Show details" button, says that the installer was unable to downolad a valid package from the server.
Then I've downloaded the complete installation, even if I got a valid internet connection, and retried.
That solved the problem.
I believe that the installer can't go through some firewall, while the browser does.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the installer mysql-installer-community-8.0.26.0.msi selecting the MySQL Developer option, it continually failed even though I had the requested Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable Package and Visual Studio 2019 installed. I even tried uninstalling all older, previous versions of these first.

What worked for me was to just install the MySQL Server first, then rerun the installer and Add... the Selected Products except MySQL for Visual Studio, which wasn't allowed because the installer failed to resolve the above dependencies, even though they were installed. Of course, that doesn't help you if you actually need the MySQL for Visual Studio component.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and fought it endlessly.

The problem? Malwarebytes!

I disabled `Web Protection` in Malwarebytes, and it ran flawlessly after that. If you have MWB, definitely try disabling while installing/upgrading. Disable whatever A/V you have while installing, because it definitely interferes with it.